# Ruby refinement issues with respond_to? and scoping

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching, ruby-2.1, ruby-2.2

I'm trying to add an instance method `foo` to Ruby's `Array` class
so when it's invoked, the array's string elements are changed to string "foo".

This can be done easily by monkey patching Ruby's `String` and `Array` classes.

```
class String
  def foo
    replace "foo"
  end
end

class Array
  def foo
    self.each {|x| x.foo if x.respond_to? :foo }
  end
end

a = ['a', 1, 'b']
a.foo
puts a.join(", ")   # you get 'foo, 1, foo' as expected
```

Now I'm trying to rewrite the above using Ruby 2's [refinements feature](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html).
I'm using Ruby version 2.2.2.

The following works (in a file, eg. ruby test.rb, but not in irb for some reason)

```
module M
  refine String do
    def foo
      replace "foo"
    end
  end
end

using M
s = ''
s.foo
puts s      # you get 'foo'
```

However, I can't get it to work when adding `foo` onto the `Array` class.

```
module M
  refine String do
    def foo
      replace "foo"
    end
  end
end

using M

module N
  refine Array do
    def foo
      self.each {|x| x.foo if x.respond_to? :foo }
    end
  end
end

using N

a = ['a', 1, 'b']
a.foo
puts a.join(", ")   # you get 'a, 1, b', not 'foo, 1, foo' as expected
```

There're two issues:

1. After you refine a class with a new method, `respond_to?` does not work even when you can invoke
   the method on an object.  Try adding `puts 'yes' if s.respond_to? :foo`
   as the last line in the second code snippet, you'll see 'yes' is **not** printed.
2. In my Array refinement, the String#foo is out of scope.  If you remove `if x.respond_to? :foo` from
   the Array#foo, you'll get the error `undefined method 'foo' for "a":String (NoMethodError)`. So the question is: how do you make the String#foo refinement visible inside the Array#foo refinement?

How do I overcome these two issues so I can get this to work?

(Please don't offer alternative solutions that don't involve refinement, because this is a theoretical exercise so I can learn how to use refinement).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `respond_to?` method does not work and this is documented
   [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html#label-Indirect+Method+Calls).
2. The problem is that you can only activate a refinement at top-level
   and they are lexical in scope.

One solution would be:

```
module N
  refine String do
    def foo
      replace 'foobar'
    end
  end

  refine Array do
    def foo
      self.each do |x|
        x.foo rescue x
      end
    end
  end
end

using N

a = ['a', 1, 'b']
p a.foo

puts a.join(", ") # foo, 1, foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking up your example again, a simple solution could be to override the respond_to? method in refinement block :

```
module M
  refine String do
    def foo
      replace "foo"
    end
    def respond_to?(name,all=false)
      list_methods = self.methods.concat [:foo]
      list_methods.include? name
    end
  end

  refine Array do
    def foo
      self.each {|x| x.foo if x.respond_to? :foo }
    end
  end

end

using M

a = ['a', 1, 'b']
a.foo
puts a.join(", ")    # you get 'foo, 1, foo'
```